# How to optimize writing to multiple files in the background

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

My program needs to write very often messages to several files. As it is very time consuming, I need to optimise it. Below, you can find an extract from my program where I try to write async to file in the background. It seems to work, but I am not sure if it is the best practice as I do not dispose tasks (this part is commented). I do not do it because I do not want my program to wait for those tasks completion. Simply, I want my message to be written to few files in the background as quickly as possible. As those files could be accessed by several threads, I added lock.
I use static methods because these methods are used everywhere in my code and I do not want to instantiate this class, just to write one line of message to file, everywhere (maybe that's wrong).

================== Class ==============================================

```
namespace test
{

    public static class MessageLOG 
    {
    private static string debugFileName         = Settings.DebugLOGfilename;
    private static string logFileName           = Settings.LOGfilename;
    private static object DebuglockOn   = new object();
    private static object LoglockOn     = new object();
    private static StreamWriter DebugSW;
    private static StreamWriter LogSW;

    private static void DebugFile(string message)
    {          
        uint linesCount = 0;
        string _filename = debugFileName;

        if(DebugSW == null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_filename))
            DebugSW = new StreamWriter(_filename);


        if(DebugSW != null)                
        {
            lock(DebuglockOn)
            {
                DebugSW.WriteLine(message);
                linesCount++;
                if (linesCount > 10)
                {
                    DebugSW.Flush();
                    linesCount = 0;
                }                        
            }                
        }                
    }

    private static void LogFile(string message)
    {
        uint linesCount = 0;
        string _filename = logFileName;

        if(LogSW == null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_filename))
            LogSW = new StreamWriter(_filename);


        if(LogSW != null)                
        {
            lock(LoglockOn)
            {
                LogSW.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} ({1}): {2}", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(), DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), message));
                linesCount++;
                if (linesCount > 10)
                {
                    LogSW.Flush();
                    linesCount = 0;
                }
            }                
        }


        public static void LogUpdate(string message)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback( (x) => LogFile(message)));
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback( (x) => DebugFile(message)));
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback( (x) => Debug.WriteLine(message)));
        }
//This method will be called when the main thread is being closed
        public static void CloseAllStreams()
        {
            if (DebugSW != null)
            {
                DebugSW.Flush();
                DebugSW.Close();
            }

            if (LogSW != null)
            {
                LogSW.Flush();
                LogSW.Close();
            }    
        }

=============== main window ===========
void MainWIndow()
{
... some code ....

MessageLog.LogUpdate("Message text");
...  code cont ....   

MessageLog.CloseAllStreams(); 
}
```

Comment: Maybe a bit offtopic, and not answering your question, but you do realize that there are multiple nice and free loggin frameworks out there?

Comment: I have just started my journey with C# but I used to write program codes 15 years back. Now, I struggle with new developments like async, multithreading, WPF. I am not aware of other frameworks. Can you suggest any, please?

Comment: log4net is a great logging framework. You can pull it via Nuget package manager within VS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You´re opening a new stream and committing writings for each write action : **very poor performance**.

My recommendation is to use only one `StreamWriter` for each file, this instance must be a class field and you need to still using the lock to ensure is thread safe.

Also this would require that you don't use the `using` statement in each write method.

Also periodically , maybe every X number of writes, you could make a `Stream.Flush` to commit writings on disk. This Flush must be protected by the lock.

Comment: JuanK. I tried to reflect your suggested changes. Can you please advise if it is ok now? It seems to work very well.

Comment: Looks pretty good.  Also you can improve it by verifying  the stream isn't closed prior to call the write method, if closed the stream needs to be re instantiated. linesCount  needs to be a class field nor a method field and because of that you need 2 "linesCount " fields, one for each stream. Also I believe the counter could be better if you use a constant to set the max writes.

Comment: I am checking if stream is null before writing. How else can I check if it is closed? Why does lineCount need to be class field - does it make any difference? Will add a constant as you suggested.

Comment: That´s because if the field is in the method each time you call the method the field will be recreated so you will loose the counter value.

Answer (score 1):

You should re-think your design. Your locks should not be local variables in your method. This is redundant because each method call creates a new object and locks to it. This will not force synchronization across multiple threads (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz(v=vs.80).aspx). Since your methods are static, the locks need to be static variables and you should have a different lock per file. You can use ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbf0f1ct(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of Tasks. ThreadPool is an internal .NET class that re-uses threads to run async operations. This is perfect for your use case because you don't need control over each thread. You just need some async operation to execute and finish on its own.

A better approach would be to create a logger class that runs on its own thread. You can have a queue and enqueue messages from multiple threads and then have the LoggerThread handle writing to the file. This will ensure that only one thread is ever writing to the file. This will also maintain logging order if you use a FIFO queue. You will no longer need to lock writing to the file, but you will need to lock your queue. You can use the .NET Monitor (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor(v=vs.110).aspx) class to block the LoggerThread until a message is queued (look at methods Enter/Wait/Pulse). To optimize it even more, you can now keep a stream open to the file and push data to it as it gets queued. Since only one thread ever accesses the file, this will be OK. Just remember to close the stream to the file when you are done. You can also set up a timer that goes off once in a while to flush the content. Keeping the stream open is not always recommended, especially if you anticipate other applications attempting to lock the file. However, in this case, it might be OK. This will be a design decision you need to make that fits best with your application.

Comment: Totally agree with `lockOn` local variables. Also i would add that you need 2 different objects like `lockForDebugFunction` and `lockForLogFunction` because there is no need to disallow run them simultaneously

Comment: To elaborate a little more on @tom-a 's comment about the queue, search for an example "producer consumer thread" model.  If you are using .NET4 or higher, you can use ConcurrentQueue (System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue<>) to get a thread-safe queue.

Comment: You can use a ConcurrentQueue but you will still want to block your thread while no work is being done. You should try to avoid using Thread.Sleep(int). You can use AutoResetEvent/ManualResetEvent to block, or Monitor to block and synchronize.

Comment: I read the link on pooling threads. I have one question, though. How can I pass an argument (in my case string message)? The example is argument free: ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ThreadProc));

Comment: Look at the example at the very bottom of this page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4yd16hza(v=vs.110).aspx (different overload). Replace TaskInfo with your object (string in this case).

Comment: Tom A. I tried to reflect your and JuanK suggested changes. Can you please advise if it is ok now? It seems to work very quickly now. Thanks

Comment: Looks good besides the linesCount variable. The variable's scope will never allow it to increase to 10. You have 3 options, 1) make variable class scope instead of local 2) flush every time or 3) create timer that flushes every n seconds.